# Using wget to download websites when logged in to a password protected session

Tags: firefox, authentication, wget

I am having difficulty downloading websites with wget that require specific authentication. Specifically, my university has me login to my account to be able to access university related websites. I get logged into a 10 hour session and everything works fine in Mozilla Firefox, but obviously I have problems with wget.

1. I tried using regular password, username authentication with wget
2. I tried taking my cookies from Firefox and loading them into wget using:

> `wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linuz x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0" desired_website_to_download`

In both cases I just download the login-request website. Is there any stronger way to make sure the authentications that work in Firefox transfer to wget?

Answer (score 0):

try this in terminal

```
export http_proxy='http://username:password@proxy:port' && wget --user=username --password=password url
```

or if your proxy does not require any password, then use this:

```
export http_proxy='http://proxy:port' && wget --user=username --password=password url
```